# ReactJS loading icon for nested components

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

Let's say I have 3 layers of components:

- A

  - B

    - C
    - D
  - E

Let's say I want to go to /a/b/c .  B requires certain data from the API, and C requires different data from the API.

I want a loading icon to show up at B, but also to async load the data from both B and C (via `Promise.all([bLoad,cLoad])`) before removing the loading icon at B.

`- A
  - B -> Loading Icon/ waiting on bLoad to resolve
    - C -> no loading icon/ waiting on cLoad to resolve`

If I render the loading icon in place of B's children, C never will get mounted to load its data.

The second part of my issue arises when I want to go from /a/b/c -> /a/b/d. In this situation, B is already mounted, so I want the loading icon to appear in D's place until D resolves. And if I were to go from /a/b/d -> /a/e I would want it to show up in place of E.

The way i've tried to solve it is to wrap any 'loadable' component in a `<Loading />` wrapper, and to have a prop, `waitFor`, which accepts a function that returns a promise. the `<Loading />`component would ideally render, push it's `waitFor` promise into a store, then show a loading icon if it is the first one to be loaded. Once all the components have been rendered and all the `waitFor`s are in the store, it would run a `Promise.all()` on the `waitFor`s, and when it resolved would render all components.

```
Component B:
<Loading waitFor=() => promiseB() >
  if (loading) {
    <LoadingIcon />
    return;
  } 
  [C]
</Loading>

Component C:
<Loading waitFor=() => promiseC() >
   if (loading) {
     <LoadingIcon />
     return;
   } 
   [C]
</Loading>
```

The issue is, if I show a loading icon on the first instead of the children, the children never trigger.

I'm open to other solutions to the problem, but the goal is to only ever load the data needed for an entire 'view' to show, and show a loading icon over anything that needs rendered until it and all the child components have the data they need. Basically I want it to function like Heroku's web app does.

Thanks in advance!